# Update TextView numerous times with Buttons

Tags: java, android, textview, android-button

I am making a simple shopping cart application where the user can select items (via buttons) and their running total will be displayed in a text view.

I am fine with having the text view being updated on a single click but I am struggling to figure out how to write my code if the same button is pressed more than once. For example a button writes a value of £3 into the TextView, if this button was clicked again I want the TextView to increase to £6 and so on.

Further to this I want to be able to have more than value added to the TextView from different buttons. I imagine this is more of a Java question as opposed to Android but seeing as I'm a bit of a newbie to both all advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Into your class if you have price value add an incerementPriceValue and make get/set functions for the last one.
If user press the button

> setIncrementValue(getIncrementValue()+priceValue);

```
setText(getIncrementValue+simbolstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a int variable count and on the click increase the count value and set that value on the textView